# Why does this error occur in abinitio while loading to Teradata? "Input port closed while active (unread data remains)"

Tags: teradata, ab-initio

I am loading in Ab Initio from input file to Teradata table via PT_api_utility using Output Table component. It has been running fine since long but today it threw error:

Error from Component 'TARGET_TABLE__table_.tload', Partition 0
[B1]

Internal error: Input port "in" closed while active (unread data remains).
  Flows into this port: Flow_2 (flow from Inter Load File to TARGET_TABLE).000

After analyzing we found around 80% of the records were inserted into table, but rest 20% were not loaded, rejected to reject file and gave above error. 
Every time we run this again manually via another test graph from start or in same graph from checkpoint, we still get same error at the same number of records:

Internal error: Input port "in" closed while active (unread data remains).

What is going wrong in this process and how to correct it?

Comment: Seems the `ErrorLimit` option is set and the job termintates because it's hit.

Comment: @dnoeth The `Errlimit` of component is not set so it takes 0 by default which usually allows a large or unlimited number of errors as per AI help file.